# How to use ignore.case and endsWith together?

Tags: r, regex

Here is the dataframe I have:

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c("aC", "ab", "ac"), stringsAsFactors = F)
#  a  b
#1 1 aC
#2 2 ab
#3 3 ac
```

The output I want is

```r
#a b
#1 aC
#3 ac
```

The condition is to filter rows that ends with "c" (case-insensitive).

I have tried to use `ignore.case` from the `searchable` package as follows but it is not producing the desired output.

```r
library(searchable)
df[endsWith(ignore.case(df$b), "c"), ]
#df[endsWith(df$b, ignore.case("c")), ]
#  a  b
#3 3 ac
```

I want to stick to `endsWith` as much as possible as I already have other functions depending on it.

Thank you.

Comment: So you just want to keep the rows where the element of the ``b`` column finish by a c ?

Comment: `df[grepl(".*c$", df$b, ignore.case = TRUE),]`

Comment: @Gainz That is right.

Comment: @deepseefan Then d.b's comment is how you have to do it! I would have use ``df[grepl("ac", df[["b"]]) | grepl("aC", df[["b"]]), ]`` myself.

Comment: @Gainz, but I'm looking for a solution that uses `endsWidth` if possible.

Comment: Can also use `df[grep("(?i).*c$",df$b),]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[endsWith(tolower(df$b), "c"),]
#OR
df[grepl(".*c$", df$b, ignore.case = TRUE),]
#OR
df[substring(df$b, nchar(df$b), nchar(df$b)) %in% c("c", "C"),]
#  a  b
#1 1 aC
#3 3 ac
```

Comment: How could I didn't think of `tolower(df$b)` or `toupper(df$b)`. That is exactly what I needed. Thank you @d.b

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `(?i)c$` [TRE](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/) (default regex library in base R regex functions) regex with `grepl`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c("aC", "ab", "ac"), stringsAsFactors = F)
df[grepl("(?i)c$", df$b),]
#  a  b
#1 1 aC
#3 3 ac
```

If you have a *dynamic* pattern with special regex chars you might want to escape that first. To check if a string ends with `C.`, `c)`, or `c(` you may use:

```
regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^$|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}
vals <- c("C.", "c)", "c(")
rx <- paste0("(?i)(?:", paste(regex.escape(vals), collapse="|"), ")$") # => "(?i)(?:C\\.|c\\)|c\\()$"

df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c("C.", "c)", "c(", "c"), stringsAsFactors = F)
df[grepl(rx, df$b),]
#   a  b
# 1 1 C.
# 2 2 c)
# 3 3 c(
```

The `(?i)c$` means:

- `(?i)` - `ignore.case` inline modifier flag
- `c` - a literal char
- `$` - end of string marker.